# call javascript function in every div in html

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Hi I have a javascript function and I want it to call when the c_id loops each. but I don't have an idea about it.

here is my function.

```
    function getCLowestPrice(c_id){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://sample.com/api/store_lowest_price/',
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    data: {'id' : c_id},
    success: function(resp){  
         // we have the response 
            console.log(resp); 

        $(resp).find("response").each(function() {
            var c_name = $(this).find("c_name").text();
            var c_currency = $(this).find("currency").text();
            var c_min_price = $(this).find("price_min").text();

            var formated_price = addCommas(parseFloat(c_min_price).toFixed(2));

            $('.cinformation').html("<p>Lowest Price : " + c_currency + " " + formated_price + "</p>");
        });

       },  
    }); 

}
```

and I want it to call when the div loaded. but it loops all the clients and also their c_id.

```
<div>
      Client : <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-c', true); ?>
      <div class="cinformation">
          C ID = <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-c-id', true); ?>
           ....
      </div>
...
</div>
```

so it will be this when it loops.

```
<div>
     Client : Hello         
   <div class="cinformation">
     C ID = 1
     ....

   </div>
   ...
</div>
....
<div>
     Client : World         
   <div class="cinformation">
     C ID = 2
     ....

   </div>
   ...
</div>
....
....
...
```

but i don't have any idea on how can I add the `getCLowestPrice(c_id)` in the `cinformation div`.

I try to use the `onload` but it can't be used in div.

does anyone have an idea about my case?

thanks in advance ...

Comment: i have no idea what you are trying to do. can you post an running jsfiddle or so?

Comment: I assume the server you're making a call to isn't one you control? Even if it's not, does this API support multiple IDs in the same query? It would be better to reduce the number of AJAX queries if you can. Actually, does the data even change often? I suspect you should probably be querying this from php and caching the information yourself

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your C ID using data attribute like so:

```
<div>
    Client : Hello         
    <div class="cinformation" data-c_id="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then after the page loads just use jQuery to select all your divs and call your function:

```
$(".cinformation[data-c_id]").each(function(index, elem){
        var cId = $(this).data("c_id");
        getCLowestPrice(cId);
});
```

Comment: thanks daniel for your answer, I tried it but I got this problem. It will only calls the first `data-c_id`, when I inspect the element, there is no problem, there are `<div class="cinformation" data-c_id="1">` and `<div class="cinformation" data-c_id="2">` but the `getCLowestPrice(cId)` will only calls the first `cinformation`

Comment: Daniel's code looks correct to me; sounds like some debugging is in order. If you're using Firebug you can put breakpoints in and check that the JQuery select returns all the elements you're expecting and that the function is being called correctly. If you're not using Firebug the same checks can be done with alert()

Answer (score 0):

You can just try adding this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       getCLowestPrice (<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID); ?>) 
</script>
```

in your for loop in php